# momentjs override the default global date for today

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'd like to set a default time for momentjs. For instance the default behavior is:

```
moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD') // returns current date
```

What I'd like to do is to override the current date to some other date, i.e. 2017-03-01, so whenever I do

```
moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD')
>> "2017-07-31"
```

Comment: Why not pass a date into `moment(...`)?  Making the desired change breaks the contract defined by the MomentJS documentation.  `moment()` is supposed to return *now*.  Changing that is a fantastic way of introducing a hard to track down bug.  What does this gain you at the cost of such risk?  IMO, even if what you want is possible, I consider it a Very Bad Idea.

Comment: Ability to set a date back in time, this is necessary in order to prevent chaging code in multiple places.

Comment: You can't. The [MomentJS code calls `new Date(NaN)`](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/develop/src/lib/moment/constructor.js#L62) to initialize itself when the constructor is called without arguments. You have to pass something to get a specific date.

Comment: Then you could be better served making a method to get the current date rather than changing how momentjs behaves.

Comment: Still requires updating code in multiple places, I was really looking for somethign to override the default behavior (quick and dirty is fine, as I need it for a single case and it will be used only for about a week or two)

Comment: Well, one SO user says its a Very Bad Idea, and other one says it isn't possible.

Comment: I know it's not a great idea, but it's the easiest approach that I could think of. Now in terms of not possible, nothing is really impossible, just might be harder than what I had imagined.

Comment: I should have been more specific. You can't, using the Moment JS library as-is. You *can* just modify your copy of moment.js to do something different. As Amy suggests, it's a Very Bad Idea, but of course it's possible.

Comment: Thanks Mike McCaughan, if you'll make it as an aswer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Moment.js code calls `new Date()`](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/develop/src/lib/moment/constructor.js#L62) to initialize itself when the constructor is called without arguments (technically, it calls `new Date(Date.now())`, but the result is the same). You have to pass something to get a specific date.

Of course, you could alter your local copy of the Moment.js library, but this is not recommended. You would have to keep it up-to-date with later releases of the libraries. And causing `moment()` to return anything other than the current date would cause those looking back at your code to wonder what's going on.

---

Upon further investigation, it seems Moment.js does allow you to overwrite the implementation of `moment.now()` which tells the rest of the library what time it is. See [this article on the Moment.js website for more](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/now/). There's an example there:

```
moment.now = function () {
    return +new Date();
}
```

Which would be easy to alter for your needs:

```
moment.now = function () {
    return +new Date(2017, 2, 1); // March 1st, 2017
}
```

I would strongly suggest using this technique sparingly (if at all) for the reasons given in the second paragraph above.